# Unicode in ggplot facet_wrap (en_US.UTF-8 locale)

Tags: r, unicode, ggplot2, rstudio

**How can I get unicode characters to appear in the facet labels (or anywhere, really) in ggplot charts?**

There are quite a few related posts floating around, but none have done the trick for me. (I address why none are duplicates at the end)

So, given this code:

```
library(ggplot2)

facets <- c('✓', '✗')
facets2 <- c('\u2713', '\u2717')
facets3 <- c('check', 'x')

set.seed(123)
my_df <- data.frame(x = runif(40), y = runif(40), 
                    z = rep(facets, each=20),
                    stringsAsFactors = F)

ggplot(my_df, aes(x, y, color=z)) + geom_point() + 
  facet_wrap(~z) +
  theme(legend.position = 'none')
```

...I get this plot (note the missing facet labels):

[image]

I get the same result when I use `facets2` for the labels (i.e. specifying escaped char codes instead of having literals), but of course when I use `facets3` everything appears as it should.

**My `sessionInfo()`**

I'm using R Studio 1.0.136 and my `sessionInfo()` is

```
R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X 10.11.6 (El Capitan)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] ggplot2_2.2.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] labeling_0.3     colorspace_1.2-6 scales_0.4.1     assertthat_0.1   lazyeval_0.2.0  
 [6] plyr_1.8.4       tools_3.3.1      gtable_0.2.0     tibble_1.2       Rcpp_0.12.11.2  
[11] grid_3.3.1       digest_0.6.12    munsell_0.4.3
```

**Other posts about this**

1) These have no answers ([Unicode characters in ggplot labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43712066/unicode-characters-in-ggplot-labels), [utf-8 in ggplot axis labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13819972/utf-8-in-ggplot-axis-labels), *this is basically the same*: [Use a half filled squares on ggplot2 facet_wrap labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21986097/use-a-half-filled-squares-on-ggplot2-facet-wrap-labels), [How can I get a unicode symbol into factor levels for a ggplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21133453/how-can-i-get-a-unicode-symbol-into-factor-levels-for-a-ggplot))

2) This is about greek letters rather than any unicode, and the answer doesn't seem to work for me anyway ([ggplot unicode characters without Cairo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41657655/ggplot-unicode-characters-without-cairo)

3) The most common solution seems to involve `cairo_pdf()`, e.g. as suggested in this post: [using Unicode 'dingbat-like' glyphs in R graphics, across devices & platforms, especially PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5886018/using-unicode-dingbat-like-glyphs-in-r-graphics-across-devices-platforms-e).

However, this is about pdf output rather than R Studio preview window, in which I'd also like to see unicode labels.

In any case when I precede the ggplot call in my example with `cairo_pdf()`, the ggplot call just hangs and I have to terminate R.

4) Comments on some of the posts above suggest the problem is related to using Windows with an English locale, but I'm on OS X with a UTF-8 locale.

I'd appreciate any suggestions!

Answer (score 2):

`sprintf` works for me on windows and Rstudio 1.0.143

[comfortable way to use unicode characters in a ggplot graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26752779/comfortable-way-to-use-unicode-characters-in-a-ggplot-graph)

```
library(ggplot2)

facets <- sprintf(c('✓', '✗'))
facets2 <- sprintf(c('\u2713', '\u2717'))
facets3 <- sprintf(c('check', 'x'))

set.seed(123)
my_df <- data.frame(x = runif(40), y = runif(40), 
                z = rep(facets, each=20),
                stringsAsFactors = F)

ggplot(my_df, aes(x, y, color=z)) + geom_point() + 
  facet_wrap(~z) +
  theme(legend.position = 'none')
```

Session info:

```
R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=French_France.1252  LC_CTYPE=French_France.1252    LC_MONETARY=French_France.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                  
[5] LC_TIME=French_France.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] ggplot2_2.2.1    xts_0.9-7        zoo_1.8-0        dygraphs_1.1.1.4

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.11     lattice_0.20-35  digest_0.6.12    plyr_1.8.4       grid_3.4.0       jsonlite_1.4     gtable_0.2.0     magrittr_1.5    
 [9] scales_0.4.1     rlang_0.1.1      lazyeval_0.2.0   labeling_0.3     tools_3.4.0      htmlwidgets_0.8  munsell_0.4.3    yaml_2.1.14     
[17] compiler_3.4.0   colorspace_1.3-2 htmltools_0.3.6  tibble_1.3.3
```

Comment: `facets <- sprintf(c('✓', '✗'))` doesn't make any difference in the plot for me. Are you able to reproduce the error with the code as posted? What's your `sessionInfo()` ?

Comment: Are you saying you didn't see the error with the original code -- i.e. the characters display in the plot using both the `facets` and `facets2` vectors?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5886018/using-unicode-dingbat-like-glyphs-in-r-graphics-across-devices-platforms-e/19610909#19610909  this seems to be the real solution

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work for me either. My hunch is this is locale-dependent. I notice your system is `French_France.1252`, while mine is `en_US.UTF-8` -- that may be why you aren't even reproducing the error.