# Display Emoji's As Facet Wrap Labels GGplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, emoji

I am trying to display emojis as a facet wrap label. However, while the emoji is correctly saved in the dataset, ggplot incorrectly displays the emoji (see example picture below). I have seen emoji's displayed as axis labels however, facet wrap seems to not work.

This post has the same problem but the solution does not work: [Unicode in ggplot facet_wrap (en_US.UTF-8 locale)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44525102/unicode-in-ggplot-facet-wrap-en-us-utf-8-locale)

Here is the minimal reproducible code along with the output I get:

```
facets <- sprintf(c('✓', emoji("smile")))

set.seed(123)
my_df <- data.frame(x = runif(40), y = runif(40), 
            z = rep(facets, each=20),
            stringsAsFactors = F)

ggplot(my_df, aes(x, y, color=z)) + geom_point() + 
  facet_wrap(~z) +
  theme(legend.position = 'none')
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GiLam.png)

Comment: If you don't get an answer, maybe you can substitute the emoji by the text ":)" or something in those lines

Comment: @RicardoSemiãoeCastro I tried doing that as well. By copying the emoji as a string, I tried the unicode as well as using the emojifont package but it seems to be some problem with ggplot. Also really weird how the checkmark is rendered but not the other emojis.

Answer (score 0):

Is it what you looking for?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(emojifont)
facets <- sprintf(c(emoji('heavy_check_mark'), emoji("smile")))

set.seed(123)
my_df <- data.frame(x = runif(40), y = runif(40), 
                    z = rep(facets, each=20),
                    stringsAsFactors = F)

ggplot(my_df, aes(x, y, color=z)) + geom_point() + 
  facet_wrap(~z) +
  theme(legend.position = 'none', strip.text.x=element_text(family='EmojiOne'))
```

[image]

Comment: Oh wow that worked! However, is there any way to keep the color of the emoji?

Comment: what color did you have there?

Comment: For example the emoji("smile") look like this:  but the color goes away in the plot above

Comment: Do you have an example where they look like that on a lot? from the package vignette it seems it's not possible.
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emojifont/vignettes/emojifont.html
https://github.com/13rac1/emojione-color-font